# Sort direction in GridColumnView Telerik

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I am having an issue getting SortDirection to work on my code while using Telerik.  The actual back end code looks like this:

```
private void SaveColumnSort(GridViewColumn dataGridColumn, string type)
  {
     var sortDirection = string.Empty;
     if (dataGridColumn.SortDirection == null)
     {
        sortDirection = "ASC";
     }
     else if (dataGridColumn.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
     {
        sortDirection = "DESC";
     }
     else
     {
        sortDirection = "ASC";
     }

     var sort = string.Format("{0};{1}", dataGridColumn.Header, sortDirection);

     if (type == "Claims")
     {
        PopulationOverlayInstance.Settings.RegOverlayClaimsColumnSort = sort;
     }
     else
     {
        PopulationOverlayInstance.Settings.RegOverlayChargesColumnSort = sort;
     }

     PopulationOverlayInstance.Settings.Save();
  }
```

The datagridcolumn.sortdirection is saying that sortdirection symbol cannot be resolved.  I've tried changing GridViewColumn at the top to other things with no success.

This is all inside a radgridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void SaveColumnSort(GridViewColumn gridViewColumn, string type)
  {
     var sortDirection = string.Empty;
     switch (gridViewColumn.SortingState)
     {
        case SortingState.None:
           sortDirection = "ASC";
           break;
        case SortingState.Ascending:
           sortDirection = "DESC";
           break;
        default:
           sortDirection = "ASC";
           break;
     }

     var sort = string.Format("{0};{1}", gridViewColumn.Header, sortDirection);

     switch (type)
     {
        case "Claims":
           PopulationOverlayInstance.Settings.RegOverlayClaimsColumnSort = sort;
           break;
        case "Charges":
           PopulationOverlayInstance.Settings.RegOverlayChargesColumnSort = sort;
           break;
     }

     PopulationOverlayInstance.Settings.Save();
  }
```